# Responsive group of images not staying in the same line on phone view

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

so i kinda have two problems
i´m trying to make a responsive container of images that when the resolution changes the images stay side by side.
my problem is when i change the resolution to a phone when testing the images show one below the other and one
and one image's width is smaller so the image shows up a bit weird

here's what i tried

html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm">
        <img src="brands/Adidas-Logo.png" alt="" id="brand_img_adidas">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm">
        <img src="brands/Nike_logo.png" alt="" id="brand_img_nike">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm">
        <img src="brands/the-north-face-logo-png-8.png" alt="" id="brand_img_north">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm">
        <img src="brands/tommy-hilfiger-logo-png-transparent.png" alt="" id="brand_img_tommy">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm">
        <img src="brands/zara-logo-0.png" alt="" id="brand_img_zara">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

css

```
#brand_img_adidas
{
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

#brand_img_nike
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    max-width: 100%;
}

#brand_img_north
{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    max-width: 100%;
}

#brand_img_tommy
{
    width: 150px;
    height: 120px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-right: 0;
}

#brand_img_zara
{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: _"when i change the resolution to a phone"_ - meaning what, exactly? How wide is your viewport then? `sm` only applies to viewports with a width `≥576px`.

Comment: when you give fixed-width of around 150-200px to each image and check it in a small resolution device, it is bound to overflow or stack. Suggestion is that you reduce the width on devices or remove it altogether for small resolutions using media-queries

Comment: @the.marolie i've created a media querry for devices smaller than 576px and decresed the width and height in them but i still get one image below the other

Answer (score 0):

This is not using bootstrap but this should help you get an idea about using `flexbox`.

So, to stack the images next to each other, we can use `display: flex` on the parent container.

By default, the `flex-direction` will be `row` which means that the child elements will be placed next to each other.

We can also provide `flex-wrap: wrap` property to make sure that if the elements overflow, it will be moved to next row.

You can read more about flexbox [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.row .col {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="" id="brand_img_adidas">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="" id="brand_img_2">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="" id="brand_img_3">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="" id="brand_img_4">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="" id="brand_img_5">
  </div>
</div>
```